# Data type conversion in mongodb version 3.6

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am using the MongoDB version 3.6. In one of my collection I have two fields one is in unix timestamp and another is in date. In the aggregation pipeline I want to calculate the difference between these two fields. In version 4.0 and above mongo provides few functions which can convert data type like $toInt, $toLong,etc. but those functions are not available in the version 3.6. Is this possible and if it is, then how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#subtract-two-dates) the 2 dates. You will get the date difference in milliseconds.

Here is [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGrsNQ7A9I-) for your reference